# nodejs axios get request response body truncated/incomplete curl works

Tags: node.js, ajax, axios, httpresponse, http-get

I'm querying a data service with a restful URL. The server (also node) sends about 955k of JSON data.

1) I can CURL the data to get the correct result, ie, it passes JSON.parse().

2) From node, I can exec("curl ..."); and also get the correct result.

3) Using both Request and Axios, I get about 600k of data. The precise number of characters changes each time.

4) Using Axios, I streamed the data into a file and got many 'data' events which I concatenated into a file. It was also incorrect.

5) It works fine with a smaller payload.

Experts Unite!! I am at your mercy. I will supplicate and offer praise and thanks for your aid.

Without your help, I will have a production application that uses CURL from NodeJS and evil will win.

Sincerely,
TQ White II

UPDATE: I was asked for a code snippet. Here it is:

```
    const datGetterWORKS_FOR_SMALL_DATA_LOADS=(element, next)=>{
        const localCallback=sendToTransformerCallback(element, next);
        const {url, headers}=networkSpecs.connection;
        axios.get(url + element.urlSegment, {
            method: 'get',
            responseType: 'json',
            headers: headers,
            maxContentLength: 6000000,
        })
          .then(function (response) {
            localCallback('', response, response.data)
          });

    }
```

Note that this is give to a require('async').each() process.

Comment: Afternoon, could you post your code/snippet of the json in question please? Redact any url's/creds

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. It works well with python, postman and curls. But with Node axios and request, the response body gets truncated. Help needed..

Comment: Welcome. I eventually gave up. One hopes some smartypants will make a suggestion.

Comment: I hade the same problem my server was in PHP but after I increased the upload_max_filesize in php.ini the problem was solved maybe there is a setting in you server you should check it

Comment: A year later... I thought you might be interested to know that I still have never solved this problem. I did seek something like upload_mad_filesize. I never found anything better than the 'maxCOntentLength' property shown in my code snippet. The CURL solution is ugly but it is also adequate.